# Magento always creates new entries

Tags: magento2.3, cron

I have a little problem. I am currently working on an synchronize job for cron.

The sync function just gets the newest elements from an api and updates in the Magento db. The Magento version is: 2.3.1 .

Here is the function:

```
 public function synchronize()
{
    $writer = new Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $login = $this->login();

    $dateTimestamp = $this->getLatestDate('/tmp/marketsSync.txt');

    $items = $this->getNewestItems($dateTimestamp, $login);

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $srcItem = $this->_marketFactory->create();
        $srcItem->setContent($item);

        $marketCollection = $this->_marketCollectionFactory->create();
        $marketCollection
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('id_location', ['eq' => $srcItem->getData('id_location')])
            ->load();

        $logger->info('found? :'. $marketCollection->getSize());

        if ($marketCollection->getSize()) {
            $tgtItem = $marketCollection->getFirstItem();

            $srcTime = strtotime($srcItem->getData('date_upd'));
            $tgtTime = strtotime($tgtItem->getData('date_upd'));

            if ($srcTime > $tgtTime) {
                $this->updateElement($tgtItem, $srcItem);
            }
        } else {
            $logger->info('create');
            $this->createElement($srcItem, $marketCollection);
        }
    }

    $this->setLatestDate('/tmp/marketsSync.txt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s") );
}

public function createElement(Synchronizable $obj)
{
    $item = $this->_marketFactory->create();
    $item->setContent($obj->getData());
    $item = $item->save();
}

public function updateElement(Synchronizable $tgtObj, Synchronizable $srcObj)
{
    $writer = new Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $tgtObj->setContent($srcObj->getData());

    $logger->info($tgtObj->getData());

    $tgtObj->save();
}
```

I've got the Object to update from the marketCollection via getFirstItem(). Now in the updateElement() function i use the the api data to update the object with

```
$tgtObj->setContent($srcObj->getData());
```

This function is just a foreach loop:

```
 public function setContent($content)
{
    foreach ($content AS $key => $value){
        $this->setData($key, $value);
    } 
}
```

I know that this method is already deprecated, but why does save allways create a new entry? (it creates the same data but with a new id)

Comment: At ` $this->updateElement($tgtItem, $srcItem);` , `$srcItem` is an single field value`public function updateElement(Synchronizable $tgtObj, Synchronizable $srcObj)`  but  here object

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I had overridden getIdentities but the name was not right.

In the Model now:

```
 /**
 * Get ID
 *
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->getData('location_id');
}

/**
 * Return identities
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getIdentities()
{
    return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
}
```

And now it works.